# How can I show post number beside the category name in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a category list showing in one of my WordPress page. currently it is showing all the category names with link. I want to show the post number too. means if category A have 10 post it ll show beside its name.

here is my current snippet:

```
 <ul class="cat-list">
    <?php
    $args=array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'ASC'
    )
    ?>
    <?php 
    foreach (get_categories( $args ) as $cat) : ?>
    <li>
        <div class="post-title">
            <h5><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> <?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a></h5>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

here is what I want to do:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some thing like this when you looping to get ‛category_count‛

```
<?php 
  $cat = get_the_category(); 
  $cat = $cat[0];?>
  echo $cat->category_count;
?>
```

This link may help you here
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-the-posts-count-in-the-selected-category

Comment: thanks for your help. how do I wrap the post number with parenthesis? @Being Sunny

Comment: @Aohor Arsalan , just concate them before and after your number